# It doesn't let me use or statements

Tags: c#

This was working just fine until I added in the or statements then it gave me these errors: 
error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `)'
error CS1525: Unexpected symbol else'

```
      if (age < 18 && age1 < 18 && age2 < 18 || age > 3 && age1 > 3 && age2 > 3){
      Console.WriteLine("Everyone got into the playground today!");
    } else if(age > 18 && age1 > 18 && age2 > 18 || age < 3 && age1 < 3 && age2 < 3)){
      Console.WriteLine("No one got into the playground today!");
    } else if(age1 > 18 && age2 > 18 || age1 < 3 && age2 < 3){
      Console.WriteLine(name1 + " and " + name2 + " Couldn't get into the playground today");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extra `)` showing up on this line

```
} else if(age > 18 && age1 > 18 && age2 > 18 || age < 3 && age1 < 3 && age2 < 3)){
```

it should be

```
} else if(age > 18 && age1 > 18 && age2 > 18 || age < 3 && age1 < 3 && age2 < 3){
```